# Is there a RegEx to extract semicolon separated values from a string... possibly containing string with semicolon

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I would like to extract values from a string semicolon separated values that could also contains semicolon but not as separator. The RegEx I found on this website (I lost the post) is almost complete because it separates the key and it's value.

**Example:**
`my.parameter 10; the.foo "Procedural Map"; pve; server.description "This; is \"my\", my description,.\n"`

**Current result with [`[^; "]+|"(?:\\"|[^"])*"/g`](https://regexr.com/6eqav)**

```
[
  'server.seed',
  '10',
  'pve',
  'server.level',
  '"Procedural Map"',
  'server.description',
  '"This; is \\"my\\", server; description,."'
]
```

**Desired result**

```
[
  'my.parameter 10',
  'the.foo "Procedural Map"',
  'pve',
  'server.description "This; is \"my\", server; description,.\n"'
]
```

Can you help me to improve the `RegEx` to group the parameter and it's value?

Comment: You write "I would like to group the key and it's value" - but there are no obvious keys and values in your example input.  your example and desired result look like you are trying to separate "semicolon separated values".  maybe you can edit your question to clear this up?

Comment: This is probably not a typical use case for a regex but that would be easier with a specific parser. For instance you need to treat whitespace or semicolon differently based on whether they are inside of quotes or not. While this may be possible to a certain extent, the regex will get quite complicated ...

Comment: @bjelli Thank you for your suggestion. I tried to improve the title and it's content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a repeating pattern to first match any char except the `;` and then optionally match from an opening till closing double quote and match the escaped double quotes in between.

After that optionally repeat the character class `[^";\\]*` to also match what comes after the closing double quote.

```
[^;"\\]+(?:"(?:[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"[^";\\]*)*
```

- `[^;"\\]+` Match 1+ times any char except `;` `"` `\`
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `"` Match literally
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[^"\\]*` Match 0+ times any char except `"` `\`
    - `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*` Optionally repeat matching `\` and any char followed by 0+ times any char except `"` and `\`
  - `)` Close the non capture group
  - `"` Match literally
  - `[^";\\]*` Optionally match any char except `"` `;` `\`
- `)*` Close the outer non capture group and optionally repeat

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oSWgyj/1)

Comment: Thank you! It looks almost perfect, the only things is that it catch the space just after the separator.

Comment: @Maelep You could exclude matching a space as the first character `[^;"\\\s][^;"\\]*(?:"(?:[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"[^";\\]*)*` https://regex101.com/r/1cKsGX/1

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by replacing separator by the [ASCII separator (␟)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#ASCII_delimited_text) then splitting the result.

```js
const separatorPattern = /; (?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/g;

const myRawString = "server.seed 10; server.pve, server.level \"Procedural Map\"; server.description \"This; is \\\"my\\\", server; description,.\"";
const replacedSeparator = myRawString.replace(separatorPattern, "␟");
const parameters = replacedSeparator.split("␟");

console.log(parameters);
/*[
  'server.seed 10',
  'server.pve, server.level "Procedural Map"',
  'server.description "This; is \\"my\\", server; description,."'
]*/
```